# Check if ROW already exists in Database using query > NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I've had this problem for a while now and I can't seem to figure it out, I've looked around on Stackoverflow but could only find either PHP or C# code matching my problem. I'm trying to check if a row exist, if it doesn't then send a message that it does not, if it does send a message that it does.

Here's my code,

```
query('SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE `case`='+pool.escape(String(getCase)), function(err, row) {

    if(err) {
        logger.error('Error in DB');
        logger.debug(err);
        return;
    }else{

        console.log('Case row was found!');

    }

});
```

Also, getCase is a variable that I can change, but even when it's not in the database it seems to return `Case row was found!`

Comment: What database engine are you using?  And what library/module are you using for the `query()` function?

Comment: @sadmicrowave sorry for not specifying, I use `mysql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is returning `Case row was found!` because you are only telling the callback to stop if an error occurred.  You need to extend the `else` statement to check if any data is present in the `row` variable like this:

```
query('SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE `case`='+pool.escape(String(getCase)), function(err, row) {

    if(err) {
        logger.error('Error in DB');
        logger.debug(err);
        return;
    } else {
        if (row && row.length ) {
            console.log('Case row was found!');
            // do something with your row variable
        } else {
            console.log('No case row was found :( !');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: While I did try .length and it returned undefined, it works perfectly! Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work for me somehow. I found another solution [here](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/07/postgresql-how-to-check-if-a-row-exists.html)

Excerpt from the article:

> You have a table address and want to check if there’s already a row with address_id = 100 existing.
> You can use COUNT to check:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM address WHERE address_id = 100;
```

> But if you are looking for a faster query with a yes/no answer:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM address WHERE address_id = 100);
```

And I wanna add we also can use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM address WHERE address_id = 100 LIMIT 1;
```