# Check if user already exist in MySql database in Node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, validation

I am new to Node.js and SQL programming and I encountered a problem where I don't know how to get, if the user already exists in the database. I tried to check `if (selectUsername.length = username)` and it didn't work. I also tried with the version from a [previous post in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193860/check-if-row-already-exists-in-database-using-query-nodejs)

```
 const selectUsername = conn.query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username= "+ username, function (err, row){
        if (row && row.length) {
          console.log('Case row was found!');
        } else {
            console.log('No case row was found :( !', err);
        }
      })
```

Username is a variable where my username from form was inserted.
I always get the error Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'
I have a register form and I want to check if a user already exists so there are no multiple users in the database, so that I can show an error if a user already exists.

Comment: You're missing quotes around the username so you're almost certainly getting an error.

Comment: Don't concatenate variables into the SQL. Use placeholders and a parameter array.

Comment: Why aren't you checking `err`?

Comment: _Assigning_ the username to the _length_ (?) of another username doesn't sound like a useful operation to. You need to use placeholders as Barmar suggested.

Comment: @Barmar i am checkig the err i just forgot to put it in the post

Comment: @Barmar have tried with multiple quotes and still didn't work

Comment: Forget about quotes. Use a placeholder and parameter to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't substitute a variable into the SQL, use a placeholder and a parameter array.

```
 const selectUsername = conn.query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username= ?", [username], function (err, row){
```